# How to display widgets inline in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the below code to display the widgets inline(in same row) in shiny

```
div(style="display:inline-block; width: 150px;height: 75px;",selectInput("ddllgra", "Function:",c('mean','median','sd','count','min','max'), selected='mean')),
div(style="display:inline-block; width: 150px;height: 75px;",textInput(inputId="xlimitsmax", label="x-max", value = 0.5))
```

It is coming out in UI, but not in the same line order. one in coming in the upper side and other is coming on the lower side one the same line.

Is there a way to correct this misalignment?

Comment: Strange enough, if I use the RStudio Viewer, everything is aligned. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to your `style`

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
          div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;",selectInput("ddllgra", "Function:",c('mean','median','sd','count','min','max'), selected='mean')),
          div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;",textInput(inputId="xlimitsmax", label="x-max", value = 0.5))),
    mainPanel()
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

**Edit: How to add space between the divs**

You can use the same approach: Example below has `100px` between the divs

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;",selectInput("ddllgra", "Function:",c('mean','median','sd','count','min','max'), selected='mean')),
    div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 100px;",HTML("<br>")),
    div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;",textInput(inputId="xlimitsmax", label="x-max", value = 0.5))),
  mainPanel()
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. this helped me. Also is there a way to create space between the widgets?

Comment: @PorkChop Based on your answer reg. space between the (in-line) widgets, I like to know whether can we control the space between widgets when they are in different lines. Let's say I have '4' widgets in 2 rows X 2 columns, and want to reduce the space between the first row and second row. Pleas see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028642/how-to-remove-pixels-corresponding-to-label-of-a-shiny-control-widget)

Comment: nice, but how would you do a 2 widgets x 2 rows in case of a `sidebarPanel`?

Answer (score 26):

You should create a `fluidPage` with a `fluidRow` and then use the `column` function.

```
     fluidPage(fluidRow(
                        column(2, selectInput()),
                        column(1, selectInput()),
                        column(2, textInput())
                        )
               )
```

More detail, look up `fluidPage`,`fluidRow` and `column` within shiny function [references](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/).

Comment: Yes. i tried this. taking your code as sample, i will not show the selectinput in some cases based on the user input. in that case textinput should appear first in the place of selectinput. but this is not happening using fluidrow.

Comment: This is not really producing inline objects.