# How to remove pixels corresponding to label of a Shiny control widget?

Tags: css, r, widget, shiny

For plotting purposes, I need to arrange following two widgets as a group and need to remove the blank space below the first widget. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
plotvars <- c("Cars","Book stores")
ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('plot1xvar', 'Plot 1 - X & Y Variables', plotvars,plotvars[1]),
      selectInput('plot1yvar', '', plotvars,plotvars[2])
   ),
   mainPanel()
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

PS: I came across links to modify font size, font size in a drop down list, keeping two widgets in a single block (i.e.,display:inline-block),etc, but not with respect to it.

Answer (score 1):

This removes the label and modifies the margins:

```
    library(shiny)
    plotvars <- c("Cars","Book stores")
    ui <- fluidPage(
            tags$head(
                    tags$style(
                            HTML(
                                    ".form-group{
                                            margin-bottom: 0px;
                                    }
                                    .selectize-control{
                                            margin-bottom: 0px;
                                    }"
                            )
                    )
            ),
            sidebarPanel(
                    selectInput('plot1xvar', 'Plot 1 - X & Y Variables', plotvars,plotvars[1]),
                    selectInput('plot2yvar', label = NULL, plotvars,plotvars[2])
            ),
            mainPanel()
    )
    server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){})
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This does not help, I do see blank space between two widgets.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. label=NULL removes the label and reduces the space between the two selectInput controls. You didn't want that?

Comment: To reduce the white space completely you can modify the margins with css but be careful since the new margins will be applied on every tag containing this class. If this is not viable you may try to apply a bit more complex css selectors.

Comment: I think I'm looking for those controls. Mostly, padding related options should serve the purpose. Instead of modifying via CSS, I can apply these controls/modifications to specific control widgets (using  div(style="...)), thus, I can avoid the big thing that you mentioned. Any leads, or specific solutions, greatly appreciated.