# Set distance (height) between widgets is a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app

```
#ui.r
navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("num8"),
               uiOutput("num9")
             ),

             mainPanel(



             )
           )

  )
)
#server.r
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$c1<-renderUI({
    checkboxInput("ch1", 
                  h5("Person ID"), value = FALSE)
  })

  output$num8<-renderUI({

      textInput("nm8", 
                h6("Column"), 
                value = 1)


  })
  output$num9<-renderUI({

    textInput("nm9", 
              h6("Column"), 
              value = 1)


  })




}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to reduce the distance in height between them. I guess it is like shortening the distance between two widgets in the same column. I know how to do it when they are in the same line [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709441/how-to-display-widgets-inline-in-shiny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its hard to tell exactly what you want but a good start would be to add the following css rule.

```
form-group.shiny-input-container {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

hope this helps!!