# Shiny align Input controls right or left

Tags: r, shiny, alignment, selectinput

I have three input controls and want to align one at the left side and two at the right side of the page in a shiny application. Furthermore, the two `selectInput` controls have to be side by side which I solved using the code fome this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709441/how-to-display-widgets-inline-in-shiny/36712447).

Using `column`'s and `align = "right"` I'm able to get what I want. The problem is that the text as well as the select arrow is also right-aligned, which is looking awful (see picture and highlighted area below).

Is there another way to achieve the expected alignment?

```
library(tidyverse) # loaded for the words data.frame
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    navbarPage(
      set.seed(1233),
      fluidRow(
       column(8,radioButtons("plot", "", choices = list("Cluster"="1","Correlation"="2"), inline=T)),
       column(4, align = "right",
        div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 120px;",
            selectInput("Something","Something", choices = sample(words, 5))),
        div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 120px;",
            selectInput("Else","else", choices = sample(words, 6))))
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you advice for best practice of alignment, but in this case, you can add

```
text-align:left !important;
```

to your style args